# All in one table or separate tables for each categories for a clasifieds website?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am developing a classified website by using ASP.net and my DB is MYSQL.
In there I am using a header table to store common records of an ad. like ad title, description, published date like wise. And I am using separate tables for store job category, real estate and vehicle categories etc.

Now I noticed that the column of many categories are identical. so now I have two approach

1) Follow the current approach ( 1 header table and separate tables for each categories )

2) Add extra columns to the header table and store all data in one table and maintain a column to identify the category of the ad.

So which is better by considering the performance when each category have millions of records.?
If you have questions to clarify to give an answer please ask.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you will use the categories, if you have to search or aggregate across multiple categories then one table is probably better, if you have lots of categories, then again one table is better.

How much of a performance penalty will you really pay for having to select records based on the category if you have a suitable index set up?

Comment: Thank u Mac. Currently I have a Bigint as a primary key in header table. Then I am referencing it through other separate tables.It means they also have Bigints. They were also primary keys. So everything are indexed. I didn't launched this yet. So there are no records yet. So according to you storing every categorie's records are in a one table is not harm right? But then some fields will get NULL values.

Comment: If you need to select records based on categories from your header table you would have a query typically like:

select * from headers where categoryId = 1234.

If you don't have categoryid column indexed, then each query would have to read all the table records in order to complete, usually this is called a full table scan. Indexing the categoryid column would allow you to execute the query without having to scan all the records. For more info on mysql indexes see the following link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: So what you are saying is if I indexed the category column it is ok to maintain every ads in one table and I do not need to maintain separate tables for store each specific ads?

Comment: In terms of the performance for selecting records by category, yes